# Backup (Deja-Dup) repeats backup of multiple folders

Tags: backup, external-hdd, deja-dup

I have been using the default tool to backup folders on my PC and on an external hard drive, to second external drive. There's about 150GB total data.

After making the first backup, I would expect any further backups to be incremental, but instead every time I run backup again, it keeps repeating the backup of the original folders that were backed up first time round, and the process takes hours, so I may as well be just copying everything across each time, instead of using a backup utility.

Is there a reason why this is happening? The folders it is repeating are old archives that have remained unchanged since the first backup. Is it something to do with the fact that most of the data is on an external drive? I'm on 16.04 LTS but had the same problem with previous versions.